# Can hash algorithm such as MD5/SHA-1 generate an ID with less probability of collision than pure random number?

Tags: python, random, md5, uuid

I have an application which uses a hash algorithm (currently MD5) to generate a unique ID in a database table. The hash is calculated based on some fields of a row, but nothing checks that calculation, for when those fields are changed later on, the ID of that row doesn't change.

Now I want to change the code to add some new features, while generating a purely random number for the ID could simplify my work a lot (it's a long story to tell why it is much easier for me to generate that ID before I'm able to get all the necessary fields' content for the hash algorithm)

I know that usually the programming language's own random generator generates pseudo random number, but I'm using Python's random.SystemRandom(), which uses operating system's cryptography level 'true' random generator, so I believe it should be the same collision probability comparing with generating the ID with hash algorithm.

Is my understanding correct? If not, why?

Comment: Is randomness a requirement of your project or just uniqueness?

Comment: @Klaus D. , No, randomness is not a requirement of my project. I need uniqueness only. And there is no global sequence generator so I have to go with either hash algorithm or random number. The current implementation uses MD5 hash algorithm calculated from content of some fields, but I want to change it to simply use random number, for it is difficult for me to get those fields at the time I generate the ID in my new implementation.

Comment: [UUIDs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html), more exactly [UUID1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1), are made for this purpose. Just make sure the node value is unique per node and when using multiple processes per node also per process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating X number of bytes of random data gives exactly the same collision probability as using the hash function on some ID's...

ASSUMING...

1. The columns you're using the hash function on are themselves unique.
2. You haven't made mistakes doing #1

I would recommend using the system's cryptographic random number provider.  Because you've probably made mistakes.  Here's an easy one:

Your system:  Concatenate column 1 and column 2, and hash the result.  You can *guarantee* you'll never ever do this on those values of column 1 and column 2 ever again.  NEVER.

What about when:

1. Column 1 = "abc"
2. Column 2 = "def"

vs

1. Column 1 = "ab"
2. Column 2 = "cdef"

Those would create the same hash function.

So who would you trust more to give you random data?  Yourself?  Or a team of operating system developers including cryptography experts and decades of research and experience? :)

Go with the system's cryptographic random function.

Comment: Thank you, that makes me more confident with my new implementation. Thank you.

Comment: Unless, of course, you'd like your generated ID to be reproducible. While I like your philosophy of self distrust, this can cause other problems in a data pipeline.